# Kivy application crashes on minimising kivy window.?

Tags: python-2.7, driver, kivy

My kivy application is crashing while I click on the minimise button of window in which it is running. any suggestions.?

I am running my application on Windows-7(32-bit) Operating System.
Kivy Version is: 1.8.0 and python version I am using is 2.7.

The error that I am getting on click of minimise button of kivy application's window is: "Display Driver stopped responding and has recovered. Display driver Intel Graphics Accelerator Drivers for Windows 7(R) stopped responding and has successfully recovered."

Comment: Give more information! What OS, what python version, what kivy version?

Comment: Also provide the console output from running the application.

Comment: This same problem is happening with me. So please anyone help for any solution.